# Redirect non-www to www except subdomain

Tags: nginx, web, dns, subdomain

I have a wildcard domain. What I want are:

- When user go to mydomain.com, it should be redirect to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)
- When user go to subdomain.mydomain.com, keep the connect
- When user go to [www.subdomain.mydomain.com](http://www.subdomain.mydomain.com), it should be redirect to subdomain.mydomain.com

What I can do on domain configs (change the record types) or my web server (I'm using nginx)? I searching the questions but not solve my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dns configuration to achieve this.

something like this
https://help.instapage.com/hc/en-us/articles/206028427-How-do-I-create-a-301-redirect-for-a-root-naked-domain-in-my-GoDaddy-account-

Comment: thank you, but my system has dynamic subdomains (my user can register they own domain), so how can I config for these?